# Java socket get request with range

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, http

I am trying to download a file, multithreaded, by sending get request by defining a range for each thread. I get the content lenght after sending head request and divide it into number of thread. Let say length was 1587, I have divided it into 2 pieces as 794 and 793 when I have 2 threads. This is my code:

```
         threads[i] = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Socket sock = new Socket(host, 80);
                    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                            new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
                    writer.write("GET " + fileName + " HTTP/1.1 \r\nHost: "
                            + host + "\r\nRange: bytes=" + newPart[j] + "-"
                            + newPart[j + 1] + "\r\n\r\n");
                    writer.flush();
                    DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(
                            sock.getInputStream());

                    byte[] buffer = new byte[newPart[j + 1] - newPart[j]
                            + 1];
                    int count = 0;
                    int offset = newPart[j];

                    while ((count = is.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            System.out.println("Count: " + count);
                            System.out.println("offset: " + offset);
                            oss[j].seek(newPart[j]);
                            oss[j].write(buffer, 0, count);
                            offset +=count;

                    }
                    System.out.println();
                    sock.close();
                } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

After getting the file, I want to write into a local file, concurrently. But I have a problem. I am expecting 2 block of bytes having 794 and 793 sizes. But the output in the console (offset and count when I try to write into file) is like that:

```
Count: 794
offset: 0
Count: 324
offset: 794

Count: 794
offset: 793
Count: 327
offset: 1587
```

newPart array holds [0,794,1587]

I do not know what these 324 and 327. For this reason I cannot write into file correctly. Could you help me please?

EDIT: As I could understand, These extra 324 and 327 is header. So is there anyway to get only body of the file without header?

Thanks

Comment: There isn't much point to this. The network isn't multi-threaded.

Comment: I get the results. But the problem is that even content length returned 1587, I got (794+324) byte from first thread and (793+327)bytes from the other thread. Is it because network is not multi-threaded?

Comment: No, it is because you have a bug in your code. The network not being multithreaded means that you won't get double the throughput by using two threads and two connections. The bandwidth between you and the target is divided among the connectons.

Answer (score 0):

> As I could understand, These extra 324 and 327 is header. So is there anyway to get only body of the file without header?

No, not if you use the Hypertext Transfer Protocol, since the header is part of the HTTP.